# Correct format to combine text and columns to create a new column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Long story short, my company's system creates a "keyword search" column when we enter in new stores manually. When they need to add 100's of stores, they have me insert everything via SQL. I can do everything except create a very long and odd column that the system uses as a search field for end users. I've been using excel to combine all of the columns, but it's extremely time consuming. I'm hoping someone can share some insight in to how to create this column using SQL so I can eventually automate this entire process. I'm a newer DBA and newer to this site so bare with me please lol.

Table is like:

```
CustNo | Name | City | Zip
______________________________
100 | New Store | Miami | 33101 
101 | Store 2 | Miami | 33102
```

I need to add a column that uses those fields and combines my own text input. End result is like;

```
SScustno100 100 SSnameNew_store New store SScityMiami Miami SSzip33101 33101
```

So query would be similar to:

```
"SScustno"[custno] [custno] "SSname"[name] [name] "SScity"[city] [city] 
"SSzip"[zip] [Zip]
```

The later is a better reference. How would I write a query that combines my text input and the columns in the table to combine everything together to create the "keyword search" field for each record? I feel like this should be easy, but I've tried a few times and I've concluded I just don't know the correct syntax to work off of.

Any help is greatly appreciated. If you need more info I'm happy to provide it. I tried to dumb it down as best as I could. The actual column I create in excel combines 120+ columns, but I'm not putting that mess on you guys. I just need a way to combine my text and column data together in order to insert it into a new column.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it right, but are you looking for a query like this: `SELECT 'SScustno' + [custno] + ' ' + [custno] + ' SSname' + [name] + ' ' + [name] + ' SScity' + [city] + ' ' + [city] + ' SSzip' + [zip] + ' ' + [Zip]
FROM yourTable
WHERE yourPredicates;`

Comment: Yes that works perfectly. Thank you. I knew it would be simple, just couldn't find a solution that worked for me. I appreciate it.